# Combining strings with fixed size arrays

Tags: c, newline, c-strings, fgets, strcat

Let's take the following example code where I concatenate two fixed-sized arrays together:

```
int main(void) {
    char first_name[20], last_name[20], full_name[40];
    puts("First Name?"); 
    fgets(first_name, 20, stdin);
    puts("Last Name?");  
    fgets(last_name, 20, stdin);
    strcat(full_name, first_name);
    strcat(full_name, " ");
    strcat(full_name, last_name);
    puts(full_name);
}
```

Assuming the first/last names are under 20 chars, this will produce output such as:

```
Robert                        Diaz
```

Is this because the `full_name` has not been initialized, or due to how `strcat` works? What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: `strcat(full_name, first_name);` That's UB because `full_name` was never initialized. Better way would be to initialize it, or replace the first `strcat` with `strcpy`, or do it in one pass with `sprintf`.

Comment: @dxiv -- what's the proper way to zero initialize an array? `char full_name = {0};` ?

Comment: @dxiv also, if something is not initialized, where does `strcat` 'start from'? Does it take the first `\0` and replace that with the new string from there?

Comment: Yes, `char full_name = {0};` would zero the entire array.  Or, for `strcat` purposes, it would also work to just put a nul character first `full-name[0] = '\0';`. As for what happens when the array is left uninitialized, that's [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) so it's rather pointless to speculate why something in particular happens, since anything could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the program has undefined behavior because the array `full_name` was not initialized and does not contain a string.

```
char first_name[20], last_name[20], full_name[40];
```

So you may not use `strcat` to append a string to a non-existent string.

Another problem is that the function `fgets` can append the new line character `'\n'` to the read string. You should remove it.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 20 };
    char first_name[N], last_name[N], full_name[2 * N];
    
    puts( "First Name?" ); 

    fgets( first_name, N, stdin );
    first_name[ strcspn( first_name, "\n" )] = '\0';
    
    puts( "Last Name?" ); 
    
    fgets( last_name, N, stdin );
    last_name[ strcspn( last_name, "\n" )] = '\0';

    strcpy( full_name, first_name );
    strcat( full_name, " " );
    strcat( full_name, last_name );
    
    puts( full_name );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
First Name?
Robert
Last Name?
Disz
Robert Diaz
```

Comment: Why `strcspn` and not `strchr` which is much faster?

Comment: @Lundin In the last case you need to introduce one more variable, check whether it is equal to NULL or not after calling strchr.

Comment: There will be far more branches and temporary variables inside `strcspn`. In fact some C lib implementations of `strcspn` simply call `strchr` in a loop. Others use massive look-up tables.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize the `full_name[40]`. Use this initialization:

```
char full_name[40] = {0};
```

Still, you will get a weird output:

```
Robert
 Diaz
```

Remember that `fgets()` function leaves a newline after hitting the Enter key. So, you need to replace the newline with `\0`, or simply a zero.

```
if (fgets(first_name, 20, stdin) == NULL) {
    // incorrectly executed
    return 1;
}
first_name[strlen(first_name) - 1] = 0;
```

After this, you will no longer get any problems. You should get the similar output:

```
Robert Diaz
```

Comment: sure, don't you have to add an `if` statement though, in case the input didn't completely fit in`fgets()` and so the last char is not a `\n` ?

Comment: @David542 yes, checking the return values of these functions are always considered good.

Answer (score 0):

I think `sprintf` would serve better/cleaner here.

```
//strcat(full_name, first_name);
//strcat(full_name, " ");
//strcat(full_name, last_name);
snprintf(full_name, sizeof(full_name), "%s %s", first_name, last_name);
```

Look at the [man page of sprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) if you haven't.